# GCD memory management

Tags: macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

In my code I need to observe that NSBlockOperation was finished and notify through *block* value.

I want to do this without KVO, delegates, or sub-classing. For this purpose I have used GCD and dispatch_group_notify. This code works well for me but I'm not sure about memory management. Can this approach lead to a crash? For example one potential issue can be if *block* calls after dispatch_release(group);

```
- (void)collectLastRunnedDate: (void (^)()) block
{
    NSAssert(block, @"Block should not be nil");

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);

    NSBlockOperation * blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        self.lastRunnedDate = [self lastRunnedDateForPeriodicName:@"daily"];

        if(!self.lastRunnedDate)
        {
            self.lastRunnedDate = [self lastRunnedDateForPeriodicName:@"weekly"];
        }

        if(!self.lastRunnedDate)
        {
            self.lastRunnedDate = [self lastRunnedDateForPeriodicName:@"monthly"];
        }

        if(!self.lastRunnedDate)
        {
            self.lastRunnedDate = [[Preferences sharedInstance] periodicsLastRunned];
        }

        dispatch_group_leave(group);

        dispatch_release(group);
    }];

    [[NSOperationQueue queue] addOperation:blockOperation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_notify) of `dispatch_group_notify`:

> group - The dispatch group to observe. The group is retained by the system until the block has run to completion.

*Note*: If you are using ARC there is no need to call `dispatch_release`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are using the group incorrectly.

You are calling `dispatch_group_notify()` before anything has entered it. From the docs:

> If the group is empty (no block objects are associated with the dispatch group), the notification block object is submitted immediately.

That applies to how you're using it.

Related to the above is the fact that you are entering the block in the same code that leaves it. That's not the normal pattern. You normally call `dispatch_group_enter()` before **submitting** the asynchronous task that will call `dispatch_group_leave()`, so that the group has a positive count in the synchronous code.

So, you'd do something like:

```
- (void)collectLastRunnedDate: (void (^)()) block
{
    NSAssert(block, @"Block should not be nil");

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    NSBlockOperation * blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // whatever work the block should do goes here

        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];

    [[NSOperationQueue queue] addOperation:blockOperation];

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);

    dispatch_release(group); // Only needed if you're not using ARC
}
```

Since you seem to be just submitting your operation objects to an anonymous operation queue, though, you could just as easily use `dispatch_group_async()`. That effectively does the enter and leave operations for you.

Also, in case you weren't aware, `NSOperation` has a `completionBlock` property that is a block that's automatically run when the operation finishes. Of course, `NSBlockOperation` inherits that. You could set that to a block which submits your `block` parameter to the main queue asynchronously, and avoid the use of dispatch groups altogether:

```
- (void)collectLastRunnedDate: (void (^)()) block
{
    NSAssert(block, @"Block should not be nil");

    NSBlockOperation * blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // whatever work the block should do goes here
    }];

    blockOperation.completionBlock = ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    };

    [[NSOperationQueue queue] addOperation:blockOperation];
}
```